# Global and local functions and variables across classes. How? Am I doing it right?

Tags: c++, function, class

The final output is 12 when it should be less than zero and I think it is because the global variable is not being changed. Am I right? What would I need to change?

central.cpp (MAIN FILE)

```
/*
 * central.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 7, 2017
 *      Author: Harry Evans Allen, IV
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "combatfunctions.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    string name;
    cout << "Hello, Welcome to Silver Stone.\nWhat is your name?\n";
    cin >> name;
    combat_functions mainC(name, 15,5,3,3);
    combat_functions Rick("Rick", 12,4,3,3);
    mainC.playerFight(mainC,Rick);
    cout << Rick.getHP(); 
}
```

Rick.getHP() should output a value 0<= but keeps outputting 12: the original value

combatfunctions.cpp

```
/*
 * combatfunctions.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 7, 2017
 *      Author: ted
 */

#include "combatfunctions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int health, attack, defense, movement;
string name;

combat_functions::combat_functions(string callsign, int hp, int power, int shield, int mobility){
    health=hp;
    attack=power;
    defense=shield;
    movement=mobility;
    name=callsign;
}
int combat_functions::getHP(){
    return health;
}
int combat_functions::getAttack(){
    return attack;
}
int combat_functions::getDefense(){
    return defense;
}
int combat_functions::getMobility(){
    return movement;
}
string combat_functions::getName(){
    return name;
}
void combat_functions::setHP(int increment){
    health+=increment;
}
void combat_functions::setAttack(int increment){
    attack+=increment;
}
void combat_functions::setDefense(int increment){
    defense+=increment;
}
void combat_functions::setMobility(int increment){
    movement+=increment;
}

bool combat_functions::isAlive(combat_functions player){
    if(player.getHP()>=1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void combat_functions::playerFight(combat_functions player1, combat_functions player2){ //This functions lets the players take from eachother's value
    while(isAlive(player1)&&isAlive(player2)){
        if(player2.getDefense()<player1.getAttack()){
            player2.setHP(-1*(player1.getAttack()-player2.getDefense())); //Should change the global value of hp
        }
        if(player1.getDefense()<player2.getAttack()){
            player1.setHP(-1*(player2.getAttack()-player1.getDefense())); //Should change the global value of hp
        }
        if(!isAlive(player1)){
            cout << player1.getName() << " has died."<<endl;
        }else if(!isAlive(player2)){
            cout << player2.getName() << " has died."<<endl;
        }else{
            cout << player1.getName() << " " << player1.getHP() << "\n" <<player2.getName() << " " << player2.getHP() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

combatfunctions.h

```
/*
 * combatfunctions.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 7, 2017
 *      Author: ted
 */

#ifndef COMBATFUNCTIONS_H_
#define COMBATFUNCTIONS_H_
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class combat_functions {
public:
    combat_functions(string, int, int, int, int);
    int getHP();
    int getAttack();
    int getDefense();
    int getMobility();
    string getName();
    void setHP(int);
    void setAttack(int);
    void setDefense(int);
    void setMobility(int);
    bool isAlive(combat_functions);
    void playerFight(combat_functions, combat_functions);
private:
    int health, attack, defense, movement;
    string name;
};

#endif /* COMBATFUNCTIONS_H_ */
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger?

Comment: `playerFight` takes its parameters by value, which means it makes copies of the two `combat_functions` instances and modifies those copies. `Rick` remains unchanged.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `combat_functions` as **value** into `combat_functions::playerFight()`, while you should pass it as **reference**.

When you pass parameters as value, a copy of variable will be generated. When you modify the variable in the function, actually you are modifying a copy of it, not the original variable.

The right way to do it, is to use **reference** rather than value:

```
void playerFight(combat_functions& player1, combat_functions& player2);
```

Or use **pointer**:

```
void playerFight(combat_functions *player1, combat_functions *player2);
```

Another thing about your code, the global variables defined in *combatfunctions.cpp* seems not necessary. And `playerFight()` changes variables in class, not global variables. If you really want to change global variables (although I don't think that's what you want), you should use `::health`, `::attack`.. to explicitly tell compiler. Or a better way, to change global variables' name to `g_health`, `g_attack`. So compiler won't misunderstand.

Comment: @user7532445 You can accept my answer if it solves your problem. :-)